# Cannot get paganation using jekyll-paginate-v2 to work

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-paginator

I have been looking at multiple answers to similar questions here on stack overflow and other sources, but simply cannot solve my problem.

I have a page consisting of `index.md` which has the following frontmatter:

```
# Feel free to add content and custom Front Matter to this file.
# To modify the layout, see https://jekyllrb.com/docs/themes/#overriding-theme-defaults

title: title
layout: default
pagination: 
  enabled: true
---
```

And this is what I do to list my post:

```
    <!-- 
        Here is the main paginator logic called.
        All calls to site.posts should be replaced by paginator.posts 
    -->
    {% for post in paginator.posts %}
      <li>
        <span class="post-meta">{{ post.date | date: "%b %-d, %Y" }}</span>

        <h2>
          <a class="post-link" href="{{ post.url | relative_url }}">{{ post.title | escape }}</a>
        </h2>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>

  <!-- 
    Showing buttons to move to the next and to the previous list of posts (pager buttons).
  -->
  {% if paginator.total_pages > 1 %}
  <ul class="pager">
      {% if paginator.previous_page %}
      <li class="previous">
          <a href="{{ paginator.previous_page_path | prepend: site.baseurl | replace: '//', '/' }}">&larr; Newer Posts</a>
      </li>
      {% endif %}
      {% if paginator.next_page %}
      <li class="next">
          <a href="{{ paginator.next_page_path | prepend: site.baseurl | replace: '//', '/' }}">Older Posts &rarr;</a>
      </li>
      {% endif %}
  </ul>
  {% endif %}


<div class="pagination">
  {% if paginator.previous_page %}
    <a href="{{ paginator.previous_page_path }}" class="previous">
      Previous
    </a>
  {% else %}
    <span class="previous">Previous</span>
  {% endif %}
  <span class="page_number ">
    Page: {{ paginator.page }} of {{ paginator.total_pages }}
  </span>
  {% if paginator.next_page %}
    <a href="{{ paginator.next_page_path }}" class="next">Next</a>
  {% else %}
    <span class="next ">Next</span>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

I have added the gem to plugin list and to the gem file and run bundle install, and my configuration looks like this:

```
pagination:
  enabled: true
  per_page: 3
  offset: 2
  permalink: '/page/:num/'
  title: ':title - page :num of :max'
  limit: 0
  sort_field: 'date'
  sort_reverse: true
```

However when I run `bundle exec jekyll s` my test post is not listed. 
But if I use:

```
{% for post in site.posts%}
{{post.title}}
{% endfor %}
```

My test post is listed as I intent. Anyone who can help me towards, what I am doing wrong, I simply cannot spot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a specific reason for including `offset: 2` in the `_config.yml`? This will exclude the first 2 posts from appearing in the pagination so if you don't have at least 3 posts in your project nothing will be displayed.

Try removing the offset line from your config file, rerun `bundle exec jekyll serve`, and see if the functionality works.

For offset usage check the [jekyll-paginate-v2 README](https://github.com/sverrirs/jekyll-paginate-v2/blob/master/README-GENERATOR.md) section "Offsetting posts".

Comment: DAMNIT, thanks! I had totally missed that, thank you so much